# How to setup usernames for websites

Tags: linux, debian, virtualhost, directory

I have a news server. It may be possible that there will be multiple virtual hosts on it.

There are two approaches that I see around.
One is to login as root and create files under /www/etc, Like;

```
/var/www/website1/public_html
/var/www/website2/public_html
```

The other approach is to create a new user wtih a every virtual host and put them in their user's directory. Like;

```
/home/website1/
/home/website2/
```

My setup is like the first one. I am wondering if one approach has any significant advatages over the other? Or is there any other way?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you are the webmaster and will be updating all the content, then option [1] is better.

If your users will be managing and editing their own content, then option [2] works. You can create separate accounts and allow them to edit their own files only.